# rosserial_client not found after installation

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to install rosserial library on ros kinetic and ros_lib for Arduino IDE.

I followed [link#0](https://answers.ros.org/question/236351/rosserial-on-ros-kinetic/) instruction for rosserial manual installation.

All steps finished successfully (rosserial_windows required partial installation of common_msgs library).

After I continued to "2.2 Install ros_lib into the Arduino Environment" [link#1](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup), I got ImportError: No module named rosserial_client.

I performed again w/ no success:

```
catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial_client
catkin_make install-DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES=rosserial_client
```

Please give me some hint.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337369/rosserial_client-not-found-after-installation/) by [roDiBgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49240/rodibgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-12**:
There is no need to install `rosserial` from source (ie: build in your workspace), provided you are running a supported OS on a supported platform. It has been released into Kinetic quite some time ago already for `amd64`, `arm64` and `armhf` on Debian and Ubuntu. Just run `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosserial`.

See also #q320046 for some info on how to determine whether you can install something using `apt`.

**Comment by [roDiBgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49240/rodibgu/) on 2019-11-12**:
@gvbhoorn, thanks for your reply

I tried using sudo apt-get install-kinetic-rosserial
I got: E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rosserial

Also: sudo apt install-kinetic-rosserial
I getting: E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rosserial

Have I missed something? Should I run this commands from some specific folder?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-12**:
According to the [status pages](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/) (see #q320046 again for an explanation), `rosserial` has been released for Kinetic on `amd64`, `arm64` and `armhf`, but perhaps not for your OS.

Are you running something other than Debian or Ubuntu? Or using an unsupported platform? How did you install ROS?

What is the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -rvmp`?

**Comment by [roDiBgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49240/rodibgu/) on 2019-11-12**:
@gvdhoorn

I am using Raspbian Stretch OS, ROS has some compilation issue w/ Buster and I am not skilled enough for t/s

ROS installed according to [Link#2](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi)

lsb_release -a --> Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)
uname -rvmp --> 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l unknown

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-12**:\

> I am using Raspbian Stretch OS,

that would indeed be one of the cases where `apt` wouldn't work, as you've compiled ROS from sources.

So in your case installing `rosserial` from sources makes sense -- and this is also one of the cases discussed in #q320046).

**Comment by [roDiBgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49240/rodibgu/) on 2019-11-12**:
@gvdhoorn
Thanks for your support, I will go over #q320046 for better understanding of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume the issue was solved by

$ source devel/setup.bash (was executed again after rosserial library installation link#0)

After, executed command rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py

ros_lib was successfully created in Arduino sketchbook/libraries/ folder

I think the question can be closed.

---

Originally posted by [roDiBgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49240/rodibgu/) with karma: 26 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1